# 'While' keeps rewriting array

Tags: c, arrays, function, while-loop, malloc

I'm creating a function `void N` in C that reads a file and 4th a then every 6th line is a number which I need to convert from string to double and put them to new array .. but every new number I stumble upon rewrites all of already existing numbers in array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

void V(int *id,int i,int *praca, double *plat,int *datum, FILE **f)
{
    char meno[2000],priezvisko[2000];

    if ((*f = fopen("zam.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Neda sa otvorit");
            // koniec programu
            return ;         
        }

    while(//vypis informacii zamestnancov
          fscanf(*f,"%d %s %s %d %lf %d",&id[i],&meno[i],&priezvisko[i],&praca[i],&plat[i],&datum[i])>0)
        {
            printf(" osobne cislo zamestnanca:%d\n meno priezvisko:%s %s\n administrativa/vyrobny pracovnik:%d\n plat:%g\n datum:%08d\n\n",id[i],&meno[i],&priezvisko[i],praca[i],plat[i],datum[i]);
            i++;
        }
}  

void N(int i,double plat[], FILE *f)
{
    rewind(f);

    int j=0,k=0;
    double *platy[1800];
    char line[1800];
    int suma = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int lineNumber = 3;
    double val;
    double d;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)!= NULL) 
        {

            if (count == lineNumber)
                {
                    suma++; //pocet platov
                    count++;
                    lineNumber+=6;
                    platy[i]=malloc(sizeof(line));
                    printf("i : %d\n",i);
                    //printf("%s",line);
                    val = atof(line);
                    //printf("%g\n",val);
                    platy[i] = &val;
                    val = *platy[i];
                    d = *platy[0];
                    printf("array: %g\n",val);
                    printf("array 0: %g\n",d);

                    i++;

                }
            else
                {
                    count++;
                }

            printf("%d. %d\n",count,suma);

        }
    for (j=0 ; j<suma; j++) {
        val = *platy[j];
        printf("%g\n",val);
    }
}

int main()                                      //MAIN
{
    int i=0,id[1800],praca[1800],datum[1800];         //deklaracie
    char *meno[1800],*priezvisko[1800],z;
    double plat[1800];

    FILE *f;

    while((z = getchar())!='K')
        {
            if(z == 'V')
                V(id,i,praca,plat,datum,&f);
            if(z == 'P')
                P(i,praca,plat,datum,f);
            if(z == 'N')
                N(i,plat,f);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: this the output]

[image: the .txt i use]

Comment: What array? Your code is very confusing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: `platy[i] = &val;` is clearly wrong. `platy[i]` is a pointer to a `char` array, but `val` is a `double`. You're also leaking the memory that you just allocated with `platy[i] = malloc(sizeof(line));`.

Comment: do something simple first. Write code that reads all the numbers into an array. When that works the start doing fancy things on every 4th or 6th one

Answer (score 0):

this code is simply wrong

```
  double *platy[1800];
```

and

```
platy[i]=malloc(sizeof(line));
```

you declare an array of pointers to doubles. And then set an array element to point to something clearly `malloc`d for a line of input.

I suspect what you want is

```
double platy[1800];
...
platy[i] = atof(line);
```